# Ensure this value has at most %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d). -Django error

Tags: python, html, django

> "Ensure this value has at most %(limit_value)d characters (it has
>   %(show_value)d)."

This is the error i get in my django form that i rendered using html when i post the data. I have defined no restrictions on my fields.
Form :
     **author** = 'PRAYAS'

```
from django import forms
from login.models import UserProfile

class loginform(forms.ModelForm) :

    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    fullname = forms.CharField(max_length=256)


    class Meta :
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username','password','fullname')
```

```
<body>
    {% if registered %}
    <h1>Thanks For Registering!</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>Create new Account</h1>


    <form id="form" method="post" action="/login/register/"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <!-- Display each form. The as_p method wraps each element in a paragraph
             (<p>) element. This ensures each element appears on a new line,
             making everything look neater. -->
        {{ form.as_p }}


        <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
</body>

</html>
def Register(request):
   registered =False


  if (request.method=='POST') :
        user_form = loginform(data=request.POST)
        try :
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered=True
        except :
            print user_form.errors
        return render(request,'login/register.html',{'form':user_form,'registered':registered,'slug':''})


    if(request.method=='GET') :

        user_form = loginform()



        return render(request,'login/register.html',{'form':user_form,'registered':registered,'slug':''})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, ever do a blank `except`.

Django forms have a means of triggering validation: `form.is_valid()`. You must always call that before attempting to call save. This is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view) and there is no reason not to follow the exact pattern given there.

Comment: I did that first!
But it gave me an operational error no such table: login_userprofile
How can i resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could think that not calling is_valid would solve an issue with a missing table. If you haven't created a table, you should run migrations.

Comment: Yeah, It was more of a desperate attempt!
I ran the migrations, no changes there.
It says operational error no such table: login_userprofile
But i am nowhere using any such table in my code

Comment: Plus Why should I never do a blank except?